# Alternative to # pound sign hash tag for blank href?

Tags: jquery, hash, href

So, I'm working on a site at the moment that has a jquery onClick function.  Well, the link is a simple `href="#"`.

Well, every time it is clicked,

1. The # sign appends to the URL
2. The site navigates to the top of the page

Is there a better alternative, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to <a href="#"> when the anchor tag only triggers a jQuery action without redirecting the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224920/alternative-to-a-href-when-the-anchor-tag-only-triggers-a-jquery-action-wi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your click handler, add `return false;`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `onclick` function needs have a `return false` in it.  Or you can do this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();return false;">click</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this as an alternative

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doSomething();return false;">click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but if you're using jQuery, in your event handler you can use

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function(e)
{
    // Whatever the button should do

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` does exactly that, it prevents the default behaviour, that would be to scroll to the top of the page (which is what the # symbol represents on its own).

Answer (score 0):

The hash follow by an id is a link to an anchor tag with said id. If the anchor tag doesn't exist, it certainly could explain why it's hitting the top of the page.